# Scrapy Accept-Language not working

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, user-agent

I'm using scrapy for crawling a webpage and the problem is that the spider crawls the urls but the data of each url is returned in a random language (en, pt, it, es...).

I'm using the settings:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"

DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Language': 'en',
}
```

Why isn't it returning the pages in english? (the web page is has english option).

Comment: Please, add 'start_urls' list

Comment: "Accept-Language" header usage recommendation and how to use guids are only there in the specification dpcs.  it totally depends on website devs if they want to use this header valur and if yes than how they want use.. depends on webdevs

Comment: to answer your question if website has same page in multiple languages . they musy be having some language slecifier in url ../en/.. or en.xyz.con/.. .etc

Comment: @MrPandav,  yep, think about it. we need start_urls list for correct answer

Comment: Have you checked what happens when you choose a language from your browser? (check your cookies and the Network tab of the Developer Tools of your web browser)

Comment: Scrapy does not control what the website sends you, try your request without Scrapy, for example cURL